# 2005 Nissan Sentra - Pressing gas pedal has no effect - vent control valve

Tags: nissan, electronic-control-module, sentra

My car (2005 Nissan Sentra) had a problem for a while: gas spills out when pumping. I was lazy and did nothing about it. After a month or so, the car started to fail. At first it was only hiccups, but now the car won't go faster then 5 m/hr and pressing the gas pedal has almost no effect.

I found a forum that said that the Sentra had a known problem with the vent control valve and that it was easy to repair. I removed the part and it was indeed broken. I replaced it, but pressing the gas pedal still has no effect.

Is it possible that the car is in "fail safe" mode and that restarting the ECU could resolve the problem? If so, is it possible to reset the ECU without a scanner?

Comment: Try pulling the battery cables off for 30 minutes and report back.

Comment: @MikeSaull Thanks! I will try it and let you know the result.

Comment: Oh take the negative off first. When putting the cables back on put the negative on last.

Answer (score 1):

(NOTE: Since @MikeSaull didn't put his answer down, I'll answer for him)

Try pulling the battery cables off for 30 minutes. This will reset the computer back to factory specs and hopefully will solve your issue. Pull the negative battery post off and not the positive, as this can have adverse effects.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that problem by installing a new battery.

On my 07 Sentra if the battery is bad the gas pedal and throttle body fail after the new battery installation look in you tube how to program your gas pedal and throttle body, there are 3 steps to fallow moving your ignition key and pushing gas pedal a few times and brake too.

Comment: Welcome to the site - you could significantly improve your answer by providing details of how to do this process.